# Interactive, randomized program in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, random

My goal with this program is to incorporate the users inputs into a sort of interactive/randomized story but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to get the inputs from the users to fit between `*ptrDescription`, `*ptrBeginning`, `*ptrMiddle`, and `*ptrEnd`. Any help would be much, much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){

    int i;
    char name[20];
    char color[20];
    int age;
    char sentence[1];
    //array of pointers to char arrays
    char *ptrDescription[]={"the painfully handsome","the one and only","who seemed much older than"};
    char *ptrBeginning[]={"was blissfully ignoring","could clearly see","had no idea"};
    char *ptrMiddle[]={"the huge truck","the falling meteor","the bucket of milk","the mailman","the most powerful wizard"};
    char *ptrEnd[]={"that was barreling toward them.","on the horizon."};

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Enter your first name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    printf("\nEnter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("\nEnter your favorite color: ");
    scanf("%s", &color);


    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        //strcpy(sentence,ptrDescription[rand()%3]);
        //strcat(sentence," ");
        //strcat(sentence,ptrBeginning[rand()%3]);
        //strcat(sentence," ");
        //strcat(sentence,ptrMiddle[rand()%5]);
        //strcat(sentence," ");
        //strcat(sentence,ptrEnd[rand()%2]);
        //strcat(sentence,".");
        //sentence[0]=toupper(sentence[0]);

        puts(sentence);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

I've edited a section of my code so that directly following `for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)` it now looks like this:

```
snprintf(sentence, sizeof sentence,"%s, %s %d year old, %s %s %s %s", name, ptrDescription[rand()%3], age,ptrBeginning[rand()%3], ptrMiddle[rand()%5], ptrEnd[rand()%2]);
```

There are tons of strange characters after the sentence in the output, like Japanese characters and stuff. I'm not sure why they're there, though. This is what it looks like exactly:

"Enter your first name: Justin

Enter your age: 20
Justin, the arrogant 20 year old, was purposefully ignoring the most powerful wizard that was barreling toward them. 汽$0HβHζ(ﾃﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌH・(DｷHH広$0陏&・汽$0ﾀHζ(ﾃﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌﾌH WH・ H櫛H・t9HνHﾃ<"

Anyone know how I can get rid of them?

Comment: Hi Justin. What is it that you want to do? Make the user set a seed for the rand() function? Or use user input instead of rand()?

Comment: I'm trying to have the output be something like "Justin, the painfully handsome 20 year old, was blissfully ignoring the bucket of milk that was barreling toward them" and then have the story be randomized every time the program was re-run.

Comment: `*ptrDescription` etc. are the first elements of their respective arrays (not the pointers to!). Not sure you actually want those, I suspect you want the **length** of the **arrays** `ptrDescription` etc.

Comment: `char sentence[1]; ... strcpy(sentence,ptrDescription[rand()%3]);` --> not enough room in `sentence`.  Maybe `char sentence[1000];`

Comment: Always check the results of functions which micht encounter an error like `scanf` And limit the user-input for scanf. As-is, it is an invitation to _buffer overflow_, aka _undefined behaviour_.

Comment: Note: No need for `strcat(sentence,".");` unless you want `".."`.

Comment: `char sentence[1000]; ... snprintf(sentence, sizeof sentence, "%s %s %s %s", ptrDescription[rand()%3], ptrBeginning[rand()%3], ptrMiddle[rand()%5], sentence,ptrEnd[rand()%2]);`

Comment: How would I get this program to only output one variation of the sentence per run? Right now it'll output around 100, but I only want one

Comment: @chux I've used your line of code her to replace a lot of my code but I'm now getting a bunch of strange characters in my output that you'll see in my edits to my post above. How do I fix that?

Comment: How is `sentence` declared?

Comment: I count 7 specifiers yet only 6 parameters after the format.

Comment: @chux I've now gotten rid of sentence so the code looks like this `printf("\n%s, %s %d year old, %s %s %s %s.", name, ptrDescription[rand()%3], age, ptrBeginning[rand()%3], ptrMiddle[rand()%5], ptrEnd[rand()%2]);` but I'm still getting some weird output. This time instead of Japanese characters, it just says "set_invalid_paramter_handler" after the normal output.

Comment: Still 7 printf specifiers yet only 6 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a name and an age, it's just a matter of inserting them into the correct place in `sentence`, right?  So `strcat(sentence, name)` would work for name.  `age` is a little trickier since you have to format the number first, and `strcat` won't do it for you.  One solution would be to use `sprintf(buf, "%d", age)`, and then concatenate `buf` (which is a scratch char array you would have to declare).

Any time you work with strings in C, you have to be concerned about having enough space in the target buffer.  Your program can run out of space during both input and output.  For the output, I would get rid of `sentence` altogether; since you just end up writing to stdout I would `printf("%s", [part])` each part as you go along.  For reading, `scanf` supports adding a length argument to the format string.

If you use one of the *printf functions, there are 2 things you must be careful about:

1. The arguments you pass are correct for the format string you use
2. Your buffer ends up null-terminated

Your current problem is with #1 - your format string promises 7 arguments to follow, but you only supply 6.  `snprintf` grabs a "random" 7th value from the stack, interprets it as a char pointer, and copies whatever it finds there to `sentence`.  You could see similar problems if your format string promised a char pointer but you placed an int in a given position.  In this case the format string is a constant, so a smart compiler can validate that your format string matches the subsequent parameters.  You'll want to get into the habit of taking compiler warnings seriously and not ignoring them.

The second point could be an issue if your sentence ended up bigger than your sentence buffer.  If there is no room for a null-terminator, one won't be applied.  You can check the return value of `snprintf`, or you can defensively always write a 0 to the last array position.

Comment: This helps quite a bit, but could you give me and example of the `printf("%s", [part])` output you're talking about? I'm trying to do it but I'm not sure how to keep the randomized outcomes.

Comment: If you see my edits to my post above, I've actually kinda figured out what you mentioned, but now I'm getting a strange output that I'm not sure how to fix. Any ideas?